# remote syslog server not getting IP address from syslog-ng when forwarding apache log

Tags: syslog-ng

I am using a syslog-ng server to forward my apache access_log to a rsyslog server.

Here is pertinent parts of my syslog-ng.conf file

```
source s_http {
    file("/var/log/httpd/access_log" program-override("apache_access_log"));
};

...

destination loghost { tcp("10.0.0.48" port(514)); };

...

log { source(s_http); destination(loghost); };
```

The problem is that syslog-ng does not include the IP address from the apache access_log file in the data it sends.

For example the line from my apache access_log file that looks like this:

```
10.0.0.181 - oauthuser [26/Aug/2019:21:40:02 +0000] "POST /api/v1/vm/event/ HTTP/1.1" 201 392 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
```

ends up on the remote rsyslog as:

```
 - oauthuser [26/Aug/2019:21:40:02 +0000] "POST /api/v1/vm/event/ HTTP/1.1" 201 392 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0"
```

I verified with `tcpdump` that the IP address is not in the out going packet so syslog-ng removed for some reason.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the `no-parse` option like so:

```
source s_http {
    file("/var/log/httpd/access_log" program-override("apache_access_log") flags("no-parse"));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a not-very-old version of syslog-ng, it should have a dedicated parser for apache access logs to do the trick: http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/administration-guide/parser-parse-and-segment-structured-messages/apache-access-log-parser